# IE 11 ignores nth-child and last-child

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

Can someone tell me why IE 11 ignores at all the following rule of my css file ?

```
.navigation.menu ul li:nth-child(7):hover ul,
.navigation.menu ul li:nth-child(8):hover ul,
.navigation.menu ul li:last-child:hover ul {

     right:0;left:initial;

}
```

This rule is being read and working as expected by all other browsers, but IE doesn't even see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have the right doctype, I don't think your selector is the problem, it's the rule set.

IE doesn't understand the `initial` keyword. (And neither does Firefox, for that matter — it supports it with a prefix, `-moz-initial`.)

Since the initial value of `left` is `auto`, you can use that instead for the best compatibility with browsers:

```
right:0;left:auto;
```